# Order of Goroutine Unblocking on Single Channel

Tags: go, channel

Does order in which the Goroutines block on a channel determine the order they will unblock? I'm not concerned with the order of the messages that are sent (they're guaranteed to be ordered), but the order of the Goroutines that'll unblock.

Imagine a empty Channel `ch` shared between multiple Goroutines (1, 2, and 3), with each Goroutine trying to receive a message on `ch`. Since `ch` is empty, each Goroutine will block. When I send a message to `ch`, will Goroutine 1 unblock first? Or could 2 or 3 possibly receive the first message? (Or vice-versa, with the Goroutines trying to send)

I have a [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0KBAfa2TsO) that seems to suggest that the order in which Goroutines block is the order in which they are unblocked, but I'm not sure if this is an undefined behavior because of the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question - it touches on some important issues when doing concurrent design. As has already been stated, the answer to your specific question is, according to the current implementation, FIFO based. It's unlikely ever to be different, except perhaps if the implementers decided, say, a LIFO was better for some reason.

There is **no guarantee**, though. So you should avoid creating code that *relies* on a particular implementation.

The broader question concerns **non-determinism**, **fairness** and **starvation**.

Perhaps surprisingly, non-determinism in a CSP-based system *does not* come from things happening in parallel. It is *possible* because of concurrency, but not *because* of concurrency. Instead, **non-determinism arises when a choice is made**. In the formal algebra of CSP, this is modelled mathematically. Fortunately, you don't need to know the maths to be able to use Go. But formally, two goroutines code execute in parallel and the outcome could still be deterministic, provided all the choices are eliminated.

Go allows choices that introduce non-determinism explicitly via `select` and implicitly via ends of channels being shared between goroutines. If you have point-to-point (one reader, one writer) channels, the second kind does not arise. So if it's important in a particular situation, you have a design choice you can make.

**Fairness** and **starvation** are typically opposite sides of the same coin. Starvation is one of those dynamic problems (along with deadlock, livelock and race conditions) that result perhaps in poor performance, more likely in wrong behaviour. These dynamic problems are un-testable ([more on this](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/four-horsemen)) and need some level analysis to solve. Clearly, if part of a system is unresponsive because it is starved of access to certain resources, then there is a need for greater fairness in governing those resources.

Shared access to channel ends may well provide a degree of fairness because of the current FIFO behaviour and this may appear sufficient. But if you want it guaranteed (regardless of implementation uncertainties), it is possible instead to use a `select` and a bundle of point-to-point channels in an array. Fair indexing is easy to achieve by always preferring them in an order that puts the last-selected at the bottom of the pile. This solution can *guarantee* fairness, but probably with a small performance penalty.

*(aside: see ["Wot No Chickens"](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/java-threads/0.html) for a somewhat-amusing discovery made by researchers in Canterbury, UK concerning a fairness flaw in the Java Virtual Machine - which has never been rectified!)*

Comment: Legitimately cool post, but I wouldn't, in general, encourage folks to go down the road of writing an application-land guaranteed-fair scheduler with `select` unless they really have to.

Comment: You're right in the sense that a simple shared channel is far easier - and therefore less mistake-prone - I too would encourage people to use this normally. But it doesn't hurt to know that a `select` could be used if needed, and knowing how to do a fair selection is also a useful skill.

Comment: It's like someone asking if map keys have a defined order and we volunteer in response that they can implement your own hashmap. They can! But first they need to know that builtins really won't work for them and how they'll do better. Encouraging custom dispatch out of the gate will cause some of the many folks without actual scheduler-caused difficulties to write something that may actually hurt.

Comment: Anyway, if I were writing this, I'd note the possibility of app-space dispatchers, but not encourage doing it 'til they see a problem it solves, and wouldn't call it "guaranteed fair scheduling" (since that makes people think of, e.g., kernel schedulers that can provide stronger equal-time guarantees because they have more control).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's unspecified because the [memory model document](https://golang.org/ref/mem) only says "A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes." The spec sections on [send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) and [the receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) don't say anything about what unblocks first. Right now the gc toolchain [uses](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/chan.goc#L1136) an orderly FIFO queue to control which goroutine unblocks, but I don't see any promises in the spec that it must always be so.

(Just for general background note that Playground code runs with GOMAXPROCS=1, i.e., on one core, so some types of concurrency-related unpredictability just won't come up.)

Answer (score 1):

The order is not specified, but current implementations use a FIFO queue for waiting goroutines.

The authoritative document is the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem). The memory model does not define a happens-before relationship for two goroutines sending to the same channel, therefore the order is not specified. Ditto for receive.